# Video uploaded using paperclip on heroku showing no screen, only sound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg, paperclip

I'm uploading a video to a Ruby on Rails application on a Heroku server. Locally it works fine, but on the Heroku server there is no screen showing, only sound.

The model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :title, presence: true

  has_attached_file :file, :styles => {
    :poster => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'jpg' },
    :large => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4',  }
  }, :use_timestamp => false, :processors => [:transcoder]

  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/

  belongs_to :user
end
```

and the view to display the video:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="<%= @video.file.url(:large) %>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also I'm using the buildpack `https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg` besides the ruby buildpack on Heroku.

I use the `gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'`. I also tried the following gems:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
```

But the same results.

I start to think it has something to do with the transcoder used on Heroku. If you download the file the video plays fine in a video player.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've tried some different things and fixed it. Instead of using the buildpack `https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg` I changed it to `https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git`. and now it works.